# Is it necessary to use a column grid for responsive design/development?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm a little confused on whether or not a column grid is required for a responsive site.  For example, I intend to start with the [Bones](http://themble.com/bones/) WordPress theme.  I will be using the SCSS setup included in this theme.  Its grid is as follows:

```
.onecol    { width: 5.801104972%;  }
.twocol    { width: 14.364640883%; }  
.threecol  { width: 22.928176794%; }     
.fourcol   { width: 31.491712705%; }       
.fivecol   { width: 40.055248616%; }       
.sixcol    { width: 48.618784527%; }       
.sevencol  { width: 57.182320438000005%; }
.eightcol  { width: 65.74585634900001%; }  
.ninecol   { width: 74.30939226%; }    
.tencol    { width: 82.87292817100001%; }  
.elevencol { width: 91.436464082%; }       
.twelvecol { width: 99.999999993%; }
```

Am I required to use these classes in order to make this site responsive?  What if the site design does not fit these sizes?  Please explain CSS grids to me, and how they pertain to a site being responsive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Responsiveness generally refers to a site looking like you want it to based on the user's screen size (i.e., your site *responds* to the user.)

There are no "rules" for responsive layouts, so no, your site does not *have* to follow those column widths.  However, there are some design patterns (solutions to frequent problems designers have had in the past, and still continue to have) that are referred to as best practices.

Those percentages you see in the CSS are based on something like this:

If my design area is 980px wide, and my column looks good (based on that size) at 26px in width, then the percentage for that is (26/980)*100 = 2.653%.  So, I set the size of my column to 2.653% so that it looks "the same" on all screen sizes.

Here are some good resources for you to look at, regarding responsive design:

[Responsive Web Design: What It Is and How to Use It](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/)

[Beginner's Guide to Responsive Web Design](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design)

[Responsive Web Design - A List Apart](http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design)

[Examples of flexible layouts with CSS3 media queries](http://zomigi.com/blog/examples-of-flexible-layouts-with-css3-media-queries/)

Comment: This makes sense.  So is it necessary to even use a grid if you use the formula to calculate the width of all individual elements?

Comment: To answer your question: no, not really.  But, what you should also ask is, what are some best practices and design patterns I can use as guidelines, so that I don't make the same mistakes other developers have frequently made in the past? That's why I included those links at the bottom of my answer.